# How can I tell whether a web service is "Restful" (as it claims to be)?

Tags: json, rest

I am trying to work with a service that its creators describe as "restful"

To make a request to this service I have to post some Json e.g.

```
{
 "@type" : "Something"
 "$value" : 1
}
```

This is posted to a URL similar to this;

https://someSite.com/api/query/execute

No matter what the nature of the request, whether I am retrieving info, adding or updating it I must always use this URL (along with some header values to verify my credentials). The effects of posting to this service are determined by the JSON I send.

Depending on the nature of the call I will receive some JSON very similar to the sample above. This JSON never includes another URL (or part of one). It is always a "data object" i.e. a set of properties and their values. Sometimes I receive an empty response but know that the request has had an effect because I can view those effects through a website provided by the service provider

I have particular issues with ENUM values that I must send because I have no idea of the allowed values (they are always passed as strings)

No documentation has been provided for this service.

I am relatively new to RESTful services and JSON and would like to know whether this is truly a restful service, and if not why not?

Due to my lack of experience in this area I may have omitted some important information that would be required to properly answer this question. I will watch the comments closely and try to provide any additional clarification requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> know whether this is truly a restful service, and if not why not?

It isn't.

One of the main principles of REST is that "things" are identified by URLs. Having a single URL for all interaction with the API violates that principle.

Comment: +1, I thought that might be the case, is this the only (obvious) way you can see that this service is not RESTful?

Comment: @mark_h there are a couple of constraints a true RESTful service or API has to fulfill. Besides some [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) given by Roy Fielding in his dissertation, he [later on](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) also explained on the difference between plain HTTP API services and REST as REST is often misused as a buzzword term.